# C++ 14 support for gcc with ndk r12 & Qt 5.6.1

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, android-ndk, c++14

I using the new Qt Creator 4.0.1 based on Qt 5.6.1. For android build I am pointing to ndk r12 which is the latest.
But for using shared_timed_mutex, I keep getting the following error:
"This file requires compiler and library support for the forthcoming 
ISO C++ 2014 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be 
enabled with the -std=c++1y or -std=gnu++1y compiler options."

I understand that this not really a Qt specific problem. But rather gcc compiler related problem. But this problem did not occur with the previous version on Qt that is Qt Creator 3.6.0 based on Qt 5.5.1. The error is popping up only with the new update 5.6.1.

Any suggestions on how to solve this error ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Most likely, the Qt release requires r11. Note that r12 has been updated recently, and some issues with __thread were fixed.

Comment: I tried r11. The issue occurs with r11 as well.

Comment: Maybe creator picked the wrong compiler version? Check the Android "kit"

Comment: I tried with r12 as well. I think the issue is that gcc lacks full blown C++14 support.